# How to run two scripts in parallel on the same node but different cores with sbatch?

Tags: bash, shell, slurm, job-scheduling, sbatch

I am new to SLURM and I want to run two scripts (each of them take 2 minutes to run) in the same time (parallel) on the same node, same socket, but on different cores. I have a system where one node has 2 sockets, and each socket has 10 cores.

Based on what I have read in one other question ([SLURM: How can I run different executables on parallel on the same compute node or in different nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412809/slurm-how-can-i-run-different-executables-on-parallel-on-the-same-compute-node)) I came up with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -J script
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --partition=xeon
#SBATCH --output=OUTPUT.txt
#SBATCH --hint=nomultithread
ml intel
module load openmpi
srun -c 1 --exclusive ./runScript1 &
srun -c 1 --exclusive ./runScript2 &

wait
```

But when I am typing the `squeue --job [jobID]` in a repetitive way I see that it takes 4 minutes for the both scripts to execute, which makes me think that they are run sequentially (after the first one is finished, starts the second one).

I have tried also to use `taskset` to select specific core, but I had some errors.

I am running the script from above using `sbatch`.

1. Please tell me if I am assuming wrong or doing something wrong.
2. It is possible to select a specific core to run on, by including `taskset` or `--cpu-bind` option in my code?